# How can i pass data back to parent view controller. am using addSubView method to show child view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

How can i pass data back to parent view controller. im using addSubView method to show child view.

```
addFields = [[AddFields alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddFields" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:addFields.view];
```

Now i want to sent data from "AddFields" view to my parent controller. How can i do that. Can anyone help me..

Comment: **This question is not related to Xcode.** Retagged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way to do is using **NSNotificationCenter** see this [example](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/09/use-of-nsnotificationcenter-object-to.html)

Post you notification from your AddFields when you want to send the object

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificaiton_name" object:object_you_want_to_send];
```

And in your parent view controller add observer for the NSNotificationCenter

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method_you_want_to_call:) name:@"notificaiton_name" object:nil];
```

Define your **method_you_want_to_call:** something like this

```
-(void) method_you_want_to_call:(NSNotification *) obj{
     //lets say you are sending string as object
     NSString *string=(NSString *) [obj object] ;
}
```

NOTE: **notificaiton_name** must match

Other way you can use **Delegate Protocol** method... See this [example](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/09/creating-delegate-for-custom-class.html)

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. I think I prefer it over the protocol/delegate approach as the code is more streamlined. Thanks

Comment: This should only be used for broadcasting messages to more than one object. Delegation is the pattern you want for talking to a single parent object, or blocks.

Comment: Absolutely wrong design pattern for this case. Use DELEGATION Pattern

Answer (score 3):

Use [Delegate](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) for backward passing of data between child to parent view.

Answer (score 0):

The most common method is as follows:
First initialise a string/int/float/.. (according to your need) in the parent controller.
For example: `NString *string;`

Then in the AddFields view, import parent controller and then make an object of the parent controller view.

```
ParentViewController *object=[[ParentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ParentViewController" bundle:nil];

            object.string=theValueYouWantToPass;
```