# calling a specific method when viewcontroller is resigned

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers: RootViewController and DetailViewController

I define a `Push Segue` to `DetailViewController` from `RootViewController` in Storyboard, and I set its ID to `ShowDetailView`. I can then set up various variables in DetailViewController using the method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetailView"]) {
    }
}
```

My Question: Is there a way to call a method (performed in `RootViewController`) when I resign from `DetailViewController` back to `RootViewController`? I'm using the following code to resign:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Comment: i think you can make PushViewControllerAnimated it will help

Comment: A method of what class do you have in mind? The call of `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];` is part of some method that executes before you return the control, but I understand that you need something else. Please clarify.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight clarified my question. thanks

Comment: @Auser Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6203799/335858) give you what you are looking for?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I suppose it does, if declaring a delegate is the easiest and best way to about doing this. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Auser There is [an alternative solution without a delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12524742/335858).

Answer (score 0):

By default? No. You can build a delegate for this.

But instead, I think you can perform the code you want inside `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` of your RootViewController.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self myMethodHere];
}
```

The `viewWillAppear` method will be called exactly after your DetailViewController will be resigned.

---

EDIT:
Like a said, no easy way to do this. Maybe the best way its really with a delegate. It really has to be AFTER the resign? If it can be before, you can get the reference of your rootViewController and execute your method BEFORE the resign, like this:

```
 RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*) [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[rootViewController someMethod];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

If you really want to be after, than you can create a flag and set to yes with the code above, and check this flag with an if inside viewWillAppear to execute your method, otherwise you cannot run from delegate.

Comment: the problem with that is that every time the view appears, this method will get called. That's inefficient if I only want the method to be called when I resign from DetailViewController.